# Change excel cell to date format c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to set a cell to a Date Format but when I open the .xls it says the cells are "Edited" format.

the code that I use:

```
if(System.DateTime.TryParse(value, out datum))
{
    worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colInx + 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colInx + 1].Value = datum.ToShortDateString();
}
```

but in excel it'll say `"Aangepast"("Edited")` instead of `"Date"`:
[image]

Comment: If you set a custom, or non-standard, format it will show as `Custom`. If you were to use `Short Date`  it would show date.

Comment: it's supposed to set it to `short date` automatically, Could you give an example of a non-standard format that will use `Short Date`

Comment: It will depend on what your date settings in Windows are. I did my checks using Excel directly and the `custom/date` display changes depending on what I set in custom settings. Also, selecting another cell and then selecting the target cell will change it too.

Comment: ow yeah I fixed it using `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;` instead of the `string "dd-MM-yyyy"`. alright thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem with the following code:

```
worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colInx + 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
```

this takes the datetimeformat of the short date from your local windows

Answer (score -1):

what worked for me was excel seem to only like the date format as "dd/mm/yyyy" so had to combine that with the display format i need e.g.

```
if(System.DateTime.TryParse(value, out date))
{
    worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colInx + 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy"; //format for excel date type
    worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colInx + 1].Value = date.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy"); //format displayed in the spreadsheet
}
```

Comment: That's simply wrong. Excel dates are binary values, they have no format.  How they're displayed depends on the cell's style. `worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colInx + 1].Value = date` should be enough to set the value. After that, changing the `NumberFormat` will change how the date is displayed. Some of the default formats are affected by the user's locale though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my case the format on the value was just how i wanted the date displayed in Excel and when i didn't put that on Excel just displayed the full date. without the Numberformat.Format set the full date alone wasn't picking up the Date format and just showing as General format so needed that for Excel to recognize it as Date format. So that isnt wrong as that is what worked in my case.

Comment: It worked only by accident - the *string* matched one of the default date formats for that locale so Excel converted it to an [OA Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=net-7.0). If you change the cell style to a numeric format you'll see a number instead of a date. The integral part is the offset since 1899-12-31 and the fractional is the time-of-day. You can simply store the `DateTime` value in the cell and the code will work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well im struggling to explain why it doesn't pick it up as date by just passing the full c# DateTime value, even converted it to an OA Date and just shows it Excel end as General or Custom format, anyhow am sticking to this as its working my end.